# Album Id and Duration is 0 in Content Provider

Tags: android, kotlin, audio, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I am trying to get audio files from user device content. All parameters such as name, artist or size match the found audio. But the album id and duration are equal to 0.
Moreover, if you somehow move the audio file in the system or change the file name, the album id and duration are no longer 0, but correspond to the audio file.

Here is my code in Kotlin:

```kotlin
 override fun getMusic(): Single<List<Music>> {
        return Single.create { subscriber ->
            try {
                val listMusic = ArrayList<Music>()
                val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
                val projection = arrayOf(
                    MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.ArtistColumns.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                )

                val audioCursor =
                    contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null).use { cursor ->
                        cursor?.let {
                            if (cursor.count > 0) {
                                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                                    val data = cursor.getString(0)
                                    //album id is 0 if the audio file was not moved
                                    val albumId = cursor.getLong(1)
                                    val artist = cursor.getString(2)
                                    val name = cursor.getString(3)
                                    //duration is 0 if the audio file was not moved
                                    val duration = cursor.getLong(4)
                                    val size = cursor.getString(5)
                                    val musicId = cursor.getLong(6)
                                    val artUri = getAlbumArt(albumId).toString()
                                    val musicUri = getMusicUriById(musicId).toString()
                                    val music = Music(
                                        artUri = artUri,
                                        uri = musicUri,
                                        data = data,
                                        artist = artist,
                                        size = size,
                                        name = name,
                                        duration = duration
                                    )
                                    listMusic.add(parseMusic(music))
                                }
                                subscriber.onSuccess(listMusic)
                            }
                        }
                    }

            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                subscriber.onError(e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: System files contain audio? Hmmm. Which system files?

Comment: And how does one move the audio in the system?

Comment: @blackapps File system in android. For example, when I move an audio track from the internal memory to the SD Card using the android file system.

Comment: You mean using a file manager or so. Or your own app i think. The system will not do that for you.

Comment: @blackapps File manager

Comment: Where were the files first? And who put them there?

Comment: Let's say I downloaded audio tracks from a browser. Then I launch my application. The track I downloaded without duration and album art. Then I move this track to any place on the phone using the file manager and launch my application again and see that everything is fine: that track has a duration and has an album art.

Comment: before manipulations [link](https://imgur.com/p6AHALI)
after [link](https://imgur.com/kZSsTyz)

Comment: But what is your question? Why the browser does not register album id? And/or how the file manager manages to do so? Album art depends on album id. If album id is zero no albumart.

Comment: @blackapps When the file is downloaded, the track in my app has no cover art or duration. But, if the track is moved to another location. The track magically has both cover art and duration. Even if I return the track to its previous place, everything will work correctly.
This is the whole point of the question - how to get the album ID and duration if the track has not been moved.

Comment: Your app is not downloading i understand. The browser is doing that. So ask the browser.